# отображение формата svg в виджете label

Tags: c++, qt

Нужно отобразить изображение в формате .svg.

Подумал сделать вот так:

```
       QSvgRenderer renderer(QString("./1.svg"));
       QImage image(300, 300, QImage::Format_RGB888);
       image.fill(Qt::white);
       QPainter painter(&image);
       renderer.render(&painter);
       image.save("./1.png");

       QPixmap myPixmap( "1.png" );
       if(!myPixmap.isNull())
       {
       ui->label_2->setPixmap(myPixmap);
       }
       else
       {
       qDebug() << "Cannot find picture";
       }
```

Но получил растянутую плюс пропал текс. Вопрос как правильно отображать .svg формат?

Вот [ссылка](https://yadi.sk/i/2k3Og_s2HqBW2w) на .svg.

Comment: По поводу размера — передавай корректный прямоугольник для отрисовки в `QPainter::render()`... По поводу текста — скорей всего, QSvg умеет его где-то между «плохо» и «ни как»... как вариант, преобразуй его в контур... и, ради бога, для преобразования `QPixmap`→`QImage` есть `QPixmap::fromImage()`…